# mercurial-HG tortoise windows, archive/export without .hgignore and .hg_archival.txt

Tags: svn, mercurial, tortoisehg

I'm just starting out with SVN with software I a writing and decided to install Mercurial (HG Tortoise) on my Win7.  I have never used any version control, but I think I am slowly getting the hang of it. My workflow that I'm trying to do is this:

1. Make edits to appropriate code.
2. Commit the edits with a revision/tag
3. Right click on the revision I want from the Hg Workbench and Create Archive to export a directory that is then ready to be sent to my clients.

Is this flow correct?  If so, how do I specify that two files, `.hgignore` and `.hg_archival.txt`, not be archived there?  This is for clients remember, not for myself or other devs, so they should see only the code.

Should I instead be checking out, or cloning, or something, then manually zipping that up?

It's very hard to find a GUI-based tutorial for Tortoise that also communicates concepts of Mercurial (I found one for GIT but I like how Tortoise integrates Win7 shell better).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The result of using `hg archive` isn't much different than cloning and then deleting the `.hg` directory. If I wanted to have a quick way of cleaning a copy/clone of the repo such that it could be delivered, I would keep a script in the root of the repo (version controlled) that deletes specific files and directories and then maybe itself.

Since Windows 7 comes with Powershell, I would probably add a function to my profile that:

- calls `hg archive`
- starts the cleanup script
- deletes the cleanup script (rather than the script deleting itself)
- zips up the directory

Comment: Joel, if I didn't quite want to go that far (scripts, etc), just exporting an archive an deleting the dir manually is sufficient? thanks!

Comment: Yes, you could delete things manually. Doing `hg archive` doesn't give you the `.hg` directory, so no need to worry about that one. But you would have to manually delete other things, like the `.hgignore` and `.hg_archival.txt` files and anything else that was under revision control that you don't want to send to the client.

Answer (score 7):

Use the `archivemeta = false` option of mercurial to avoid the `.hg_archival.txt` file.

Use the exclude filter on `.hg*` to avoid files starting with `.hg` like `.hgignore`

Regarding archivemeta option, see:
http://www.selenic.com/mercurial/hgrc.5.html

Regarding the exclusion of files in `hg archive` command see http://www.selenic.com/mercurial/hg.1.html#archive which states:

> create a tarball excluding .hg files:
>
> `hg archive project.tar.gz -X ".hg*"`

I know this answer relates rather to the command line than to Tortoise but it should be easy to adapt.